# Fix a nested promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise

I have an existing Promise chain that makes me very uncomfortable. I don't like nested callbacks, let alone nested promise chains. I have refactored it, but curious if it can be done better.

The reason for the refactor is that I need to add an additional functional call to this flow, right in the middle

EXISTING:

```
initFirestore()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Firestore has been initialized.');
    seedServices()
      .then(customerId => {
// here is where my new function would need to live.
        seedFirestore()
          .then(() => {
            console.log('Seed created for Customer: ', customerId);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Trouble seeding firestore with seedTemplates', err);
          });
      })
      .catch(customerId => {
        console.log('Seed created with warnings for  Customer: ', customerId);
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw new Error(err);
  });
```

My Proposed update:

```
initFirestore()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Firestore has been initialized.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    throw new Error(err);
  })
  .then(() => seedServices())
  .then(customerId => customerId)
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Trouble seeding firestore with seedTemplates', err);
  })
  .then(async customerId => {
    await myNewFunction().then(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
    return customerId;
  })
  .then(async customerId => {
    await seedFirestore();
    return customerId;
  })
  .then(customerId => {
    console.log('Seed created for Customer: ', customerId);
  })
  .catch(customerId => {
    console.log('Seed created with warnings for  Customer: ', customerId);
  });
```

I'm not happy with the mixing of `catch` in the chain...How else could I do this?

Comment: If the code works, and you want a review of all of the code, you may be able to post this on [codereview.se], but be sure to read their help center first.

Comment: I see a few `await`, so is there a reason this is not all using `await`? It would be much simpler.

Comment: dont use `await` and `then` ( `await myNewFunction().then(`) stick with promises `then / catch` style or with `async /await style`

Comment: Your `catch` isn't returning `customerId`.  Your "Trouble seeding..." catch is going to return a promise that resolves with `undefined` and the next `then` will probably crash.

Comment: This line of code: `.then(customerId => customerId)` literally does nothing.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I had not seen the Code Review link ever before.  Thank you for that info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you are doing *is* ok, if you mean to catch errors, log a warning and then continue anyway.

This is the async/await equivalent:

```
let customerId;
try {

    try {
      await initFirestore()
      console.log('Firestore has been initialized.');
    } catch(err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    });

    try {
      customerId = await seedServices());
    } catch(err) {
      console.log('Trouble seeding firestore with seedTemplates', err);
    };

    const response = await myNewFunction();
    console.log(response);

    await seedFirestore();
    console.log('Seed created for Customer: ', customerId);

} catch (err) {
   console.log('Seed created with warnings for  Customer: ', customerId);
}
```

What's strange here is:

1. Immediately re-throwing the error you got, wrapped in a `new Error()`.
2. Using exceptions for warnings

And, you can probably clean up your code a bit by lifting the `customerId` variable outside the first then, so you don't have pass it around everywhere.

**Edit** there are problems with your code, not every path will correctly forward customerId to the next then() handler. If you want to use then()/catch() instead of async/await.

One question I would have is, do you really want to continue the operation even after seedServices fails. My guess is 'no', so that would cause me to rewrite your code to:

```
let customerId;

initFirestore()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Firestore has been initialized.');
    return seedServices();
  })
  .then(cId => {
    customerId = cId;
    return myNewFunction();
  })
  .then(() => seedFireStore());
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Seed created for Customer: ', customerId);
  })
  .catch(customerId => {
    console.log('Error while creating seed for customer ', customerId);
  });
```

async/await equivalent:

```
let customerId;

try {
  await initFirestore()
  const customerId = await seedServices();
  await myNewFunction();
  await seedFireStore());

  console.log('Seed created for Customer: ', customerId);

} catch(err) {
  console.log('Error while creating seed for customer ', customerId);
});
```

If you *did* mean to catch errors and continue anyway (after seedServices), my recommendation would be to split your operations in a few different functions. This is always nicer than nesting your promise chains.

Comment: Why catch and rethrow the exact same error?  That's redundant and superfluous.

Comment: @avejidah That's maybe why Evert said it was strange :)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this. Only reason is that perhaps initFirestore doesn't  throw a proper exception (like a string) or the author wants a new stacktrace.

Comment: I see that, @Keith, but I was asking why.  Evert gave a good explanation about catching things other than Error instances.

Comment: some of the existing errors I need to investigate more, but generally, this approach is correct...marked as so.  THANK YOU!